# Javah : The selected resource does not resolve to a Java element

Tags: eclipse, javah

I'm trying to create JNI headers from a Java class using javah in **eclipse** . I created a Program in External Tools(Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuraitons) with these configurations :
**Location** : `${env_var:JAVA_HOME}\bin\javah.exe`
**Working Directory** : `${workspace_loc:/MyProject/bin/classes}`
**Arguments** : `-jni -verbose -d "${project_loc}${system_property:file.separator}jni" ${java_type_name}`
But when I run it this error occurs :

```
The selected resource does not resolve to a Java element
```

How can I fix this error?
Thanks!

Comment: maybe it is because the name of the file is "java" not "javah". Try with that and maybe that could make the difference (:

Comment: You mean I try Location : **${env_var:JAVA_HOME}\bin\java.exe?**

Comment: yes, it is java.exe and javac for compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this in my **Arguments** and my problem went away :

```
-d ${project_loc:}/jni -classpath E:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\platforms\android-14\android.jar;${project_loc}/bin/classes com.example.myreallyjniproject.MainActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem, notice that your fix is not really ideal, as you replaced "${java_type_name}" with a hard coded class name. This configuration won't work for multiple java files or other classes.

In order for the "${java_type_name}" variable to work, you have to select a java file in eclipse and then you run the javah eclipse configuration or it works when you save a given java file.

Instead of calling javah directly, I ended up creating an ant script for dealing with the multiple classes that I have and configuring that ant script within the Project Builder settings.